# d3 Animate Multiple SVG Lines

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I'm trying to create multiple lines on a line graph one at a time. I've created an object array of about 100 lines in the below format:

```
var allLines = [{type: "linear", values: [1000, 2000, 3000]}, {}, ... {}];

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function (d) {
        return d != null;
    })
    .x(function (d, i) {
        return x(new Date(minYear + i, 1, 1));
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d);
    });
```

Now I want to draw each line, one at a time with a delay of about 250 milliseconds between each line. I've tried the below approach which I thought would work, but I must be missing something because it just waits 250ms and then draws all the lines.

```
svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'lineGroup')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(allLines)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', function (d) {
        return d.type;
    })
    .style('visibility', 'hidden')
    .attr('d', function (d) {
        return line(d.values);
    });

    function foo(transition) {
        transition
            .style('visibility', 'visible');
    }

    d3.select('.lineGroup').selectAll('path').transition().delay(250).call(foo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic approach is right, you just need to adjust the delay dynamically such that the later lines are drawn later. At the moment, the delay applies to all lines. To make it dynamic, you can use something like

```
svg.append("g")
   // etc
   .transition()
   .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 250; })
   .style('visibility', 'visible');
```

You can also do everything in one call, no need for a separate one after creating the lines.

Comment: I knew it was something simple I was missing. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Now that I have that and a second transition to change the opacity on a separate delay. Is it possible to change the text of an element like "d3.select('.title1').text(d.type);" on the same delay as the changing of the style from hidden to visible? I tried adding something like .call(updateText) after the .style(...) line but it just updates the text with everything.

Comment: You can update/animate as many attributes as you like (although it won't make sense in every case). The general rule is that you specify the start state before calling `.transition()` and the end state after that.

Comment: Something like: .style('visibility', function (d) {
                d3.select('.title1').text('');
                return 'hidden';
            }) and then             .style('visibility', function (d) {
                d3.select('.title1').text('Best Forecast: ' + d.type);
                return 'visible';
            }) after the .transition()

Comment: Yes, although it's not particularly good practice to have side effects in the functions that return attribute values.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably just make it its own transition outside of the svg.append('g')